# how to recover files from an .img of VMware ESX?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, vmware

I had this VMware ESXi server which included a VM with my issue tracking data (Jira). All of a sudden the power went out and the hard disk got corrupted (Sad story, hope never happens to anybody).

Now I have a 2TB .img file taken from the whole hard disk with dd tool. How can I mount this image into Ubuntu? After that, Is it possible to recover files from this partition?

Answer (score 0):

See `man 8 mount`, especially **The Loop Device**. It says, in part:

```
THE LOOP DEVICE

       One further possible type is a mount via the loop device. For  example,
       the command

              mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -t vfat -o loop=/dev/loop

       will  set  up  the  loop  device  /dev/loop3  to correspond to the file
       /tmp/disk.img, and then mount this device on /mnt.
```

However, in spite of what the `man` page says, I suggest you mount your disk image someplace other  than `/mnt`.